# Problem with declaring ClientContext Object globally

Tags: 2010, document-library, csom

I am working with SharePoint 2010 with `Client Object Model(C#)`. I am having multiple function which does different operation with Lists and Library.

In every method I have define a new object of `ClientContext` with `Using` statement and passed the credential again and use it for that particular function.

Now what I thought to declare this `ClientContext` globally and assign credential for only one time and use it in all function. So I created a Constructor of the class in which all the functions is developed and wrote following code.

```
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
public ClassName()
{
myCache = new CredentialCache();
myCache.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential(userName, password));
clientContext.Credentials = myCache;
}
```

Now I am trying to create the `Document Library` using following code:

```
ListCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListCreationInformation();
listCreationInformation.Description = documentLibraryName;
listCreationInformation.Title = documentLibraryName;
listCreationInformation.TemplateType = 101;
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.Add(listCreationInformation);
clientContext.Load(list);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It creates the `Document Library`. But when I try to get that `Document Library` using following code

```
  List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
  documentLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
  documentLibrary.Update();
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It gives me error

> List does not exist.
>   The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may
>   have been deleted by another user.

So I need to know why it is not giving me error while creating `Document Library` but giving me error while retrieving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code, I think you are missing to load list after getting it.. 
 Just modify this code

> List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
>    documentLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
>    documentLibrary.Update();
>    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

to

> List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
>    clientContext.load(documentLibrary);
>    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
>    documentLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
>    documentLibrary.Update();
>    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Try this code and comment if you have any query...

Comment: I also thought of doing same before reading this answer. But gracefully it worked.

Comment: okay.. not an issue.. cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName); clientContext.load(documentLibrary);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
documentLibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
documentLibrary.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for the gift